# Get cell color from .xlsx

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to read excel file.
I want to get cell color from "xlsx" file.
I tried to get color so:

```
wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx', data_only=True)
sh = wb[Sheet1]
sh['A1'].fill.start_color.index #Green Color
```

I get "11L", but i need to get rgb color, how i can do it?

Comment: Please look at my solution below. It works for XLSX file. It gives the color code, both in Hex and RGB tuple.

Comment: In `cell.fill.start_color` there may be multiple ways of color representation. More here: [Colors](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.colors.html) To get the required RGB values, I recommend: [Relevant Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429823)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the sheet is using the built-on colour index. The mapping for these is in the source of [`openpyxl.styles.color`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/styles/colors.html)

```
COLOR_INDEX = (
    '00000000', '00FFFFFF', '00FF0000', '0000FF00', '000000FF', #0-4
    '00FFFF00', '00FF00FF', '0000FFFF', '00000000', '00FFFFFF', #5-9
    '00FF0000', '0000FF00', '000000FF', '00FFFF00', '00FF00FF', #10-14
    '0000FFFF', '00800000', '00008000', '00000080', '00808000', #15-19
    '00800080', '00008080', '00C0C0C0', '00808080', '009999FF', #20-24
    '00993366', '00FFFFCC', '00CCFFFF', '00660066', '00FF8080', #25-29
    '000066CC', '00CCCCFF', '00000080', '00FF00FF', '00FFFF00', #30-34
    '0000FFFF', '00800080', '00800000', '00008080', '000000FF', #35-39
    '0000CCFF', '00CCFFFF', '00CCFFCC', '00FFFF99', '0099CCFF', #40-44
    '00FF99CC', '00CC99FF', '00FFCC99', '003366FF', '0033CCCC', #45-49
    '0099CC00', '00FFCC00', '00FF9900', '00FF6600', '00666699', #50-54
    '00969696', '00003366', '00339966', '00003300', '00333300', #55-59
    '00993300', '00993366', '00333399', '00333333', 'System Foreground', 'System Background' #60-64
)
```

11L corresponds to 0000FF00 (hexadecimal) for which the rgb tuple would be green (0,255,0).

Comment: It's worth noting that this index can be extended or indeed overwritten.

Comment: If '11L' is converted in hexadecimal i get '31314c'. Maybe you are using other method. I don't understand how are you geting "0000FF00"

Comment: Sorry i understood how to get color from cell

Comment: Doesn't work at all, i have index=7, which gives me cyan in COLOR_INDEX, but my cell is orange, what helped me is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429823/getting-excel-cell-background-themed-color-as-hex-with-openpyxl)

Comment: As I noted in my comment: the index isn't fixed.

Answer (score 10):

I got color from cell so:

```
wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsx', data_only=True)
sh = wb[Sheet1]
i=sh['A1'].fill.start_color.index #Green Color
Colors=styles.colors.COLOR_INDEX
result = str(Coloros[i])
result= "#"+result[2:]
```

Comment: This has typing errors. There is no need to convert to a string (it is already) and the full value is actually aRGB with the a standing for the alpha value of the colour.

Comment: Not only it has spelling mistakes, it also gives **TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str** when you are trying to do `str(Coloros[i])`. Since `str(Coloros[i])` gives a tuple with 66 members.Please look at my solution.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution for `xlsx` files using `openpyxl` library.   `A2` is the cell whose color code we need to find out.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
excel_file = 'color_codes.xlsx' 
wb = load_workbook(excel_file, data_only = True)
sh = wb['Sheet1']
color_in_hex = sh['A2'].fill.start_color.index # this gives you Hexadecimal value of the color
print ('HEX =',color_in_hex) 
print('RGB =', tuple(int(color_in_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))) # Color in RGB
```

Answer (score 1):

with `openpyxl==3.0.7` hex colour can be obtained by

```
val = int(_cell.fill.start_color.index, 16)
hex_color = "%06x" % (val && 0xFFFFFF)
```

Comment: Gives an error to me:   hex_color = "%06x" % (val && 0xFFFFFF)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you share what was the the value in Val when the error occurred. @ReneSmit

Comment: I get an error: "TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base". Version 3.0.10 btw

Comment: How did you find that ? Thank you, it works well !

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Sumit Pokhrel *almost* worked for me. I had to change the last line to

```
print('RGB =', tuple(int(color_in_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (2, 4, 6))) # Color in RGB
```