# How can I get the rgb value of a excel cell using openpyxl?

Tags: python, rgb, openpyxl

I'm having trouble extracting the rgb value of a cell (specifically the fill) from an excel sheet.

This doesn't work:

```
my_cell.fill.fgColor.rgb
```

[I've looked at this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736419/get-cell-color-from-xlsx)

For the former answer, I don't get how "11L" is supposed to correspond to a hex value. For the later, the following code doesn't work either:

```
color_index = my_cell.fill.start_color.index
color_map = openpyxl.styles.colors.COLOR_INDEX
rgb = color_map[color_index]
```

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get cell color from .xlsx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736419/get-cell-color-from-xlsx)

Comment: I explicitly say I checked that. Cmon man.

Comment: Ever found an answer to this @Aozturk ?

Comment: @ArthurBlaquart It has been a while, I think I ended up implementing a kludgy system where I called an excel Macro from python.