# Get count of a color in cells of my xlsx file python

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

i have a .xlsx file which has 3 columns.

```
id   name  age
1    jon    10       #jon cell is red
2    bob    54       #bob cell is red
3    rob    77  
4    sal    22       #sal cell is red
5    wil    47
6    nia    32
```

in my `column 'name' jon ,bob, sal cell are red colored`, rest cells of column 'name' are green colored.

i want to find the count of `red colored cells` i.e in this case `3`.

this is just an example, i have .xlsx files which have more than 1000 rows and it would be very difficult to manually count red color cells.

I tried it using openpyxl and xlrd but could'nt find much

any leads would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736419/get-cell-color-from-xlsx)

First we need to load the workbook and then work with a selected sheet from that workbook, for that we do the following:

```
import openpyxl as px

#Loading the workbook into python
wb = px.load_workbook('FileName.xlsx')

#Selecting Active Sheet
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

The second answer (in the link) was quite helpful - one can grab the HEX code of the cell colour by referring to the colour [index](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/styles/colors.html) doing the following:

```
i = sheet['A1'].fill.start_color.index #Grabbing colour at [A1]
index_colours = px.styles.colors.COLOR_INDEX
result = str(index_colours [i])

result= "#"+result[2:]

print result
#>>>#HEXCODE
```

you can use this and add all the codes to a list after reading the excel file, eg:

```
colour_list = []
index_colours = px.styles.colors.COLOR_INDEX
for row in range(1,all_rows):

    i = sheet['B' + str(row)].fill.start_color.index
    result = str(index_colours [i])
    result= "#"+result[2:]
    colour_list.append(result)
```

and count HEX codes referring to Red

```
red = '#FF0000'
print colour_list.count(red)
#>>> 3
```

Comment: how are you loading the xlsx file?  into which variable, how are you defining 'i' ?

Comment: sheet['A1'] ?? my sheet name is sheet1

Comment: Really you should show some attempt to answering your own question as this isnt a code writing service. To learn how to integrate Excel and python I suggest looking [Here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/)

Comment: It gives **TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str** when you are trying to do `str(Coloros[i])`. Since `str(Coloros[i])` gives a tuple with 66 members.Please look at my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for `xlsx` files using `openpyxl` library. `A2` is the cell whose color code we need to find out.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
excel_file = 'color_codes.xlsx' 
wb = load_workbook(excel_file, data_only = True)
sh = wb['Sheet1']
color_in_hex = sh['A2'].fill.start_color.index # this gives you Hexadecimal value of the color
print ('HEX =',color_in_hex) 
print('RGB =', tuple(int(color_in_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))) # Color in RGB
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for

```
'TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str': result = str(index_colours [i])
```

Actually, `i` or color index is returned as `String`. Hence, we get above error when we pass it as an index for `index_colors`. It is necessary to convert `i` into `int` as shown below:

```
result = str(index_colors[int(i)])
```