# Getting Excel cell background themed color as hex with openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm reading *xlsx files with openpyxl python library, and within other  data I want to get information on cells background color.

This code I was using normally, while my worksheets contained only standard colors, then it  returned me something like "FFFFC000" in a string format that I can use further.

```py
color = cell.fill.start_color.index
```

After I've met documents containing cells of themed colors it returns me just integers like '1' or '9' for such cells, as I can guess it equals to column of theme color from the menu:

[image: patternfill]

Is there any way to get hex or rgb info on such themed colors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of googling finally found the solution - [proposed idea](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/987) to add converting between theme + tint to RGB in openpyxl. Importing their set of color converting functions, I can reduce my solution to the next steps:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
theme = cell.fill.start_color.theme
tint = cell.fill.start_color.tint
color = theme_and_tint_to_rgb(wb, theme, tint)
```

Comment: Could you post here how you use it in `QAbstractTableModel`'s `data` for coloring particular cell?

Comment: Hello! Sorry, I'm not using the result in PyQT/Pyside table widgets, my idea was to convert Excel table to AutoCAD table directly instead of built-in tool for table importing.

Comment: Link is broken, can you post the code for `theme_and_tint_to_rgb` ?

Comment: Indeed, the original link seems unavailable. I stored that code as is and now have uploaded it here: https://pastebin.com/B2nGEGX2

Comment: The code in pastebin runs OK on Python 3.x up to 3.8. However the `getchildren` method is deprecated and stops working on Python 3.9.

Answer (score 8):

Following @Sib's work, and updating to use `items(x)` instead of the deprecated `x.getchildren()` (see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html?highlight=getchildren#removed)

```py
from colorsys import rgb_to_hls, hls_to_rgb
# From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429823/getting-excel-cell-background-themed-color-as-hex-with-openpyxl/58443509#58443509
#   which refers to: https://pastebin.com/B2nGEGX2 (October 2020)
#       Updated to use list(elem) instead of the deprecated elem.getchildren() method
#       which has now been removed completely from Python 3.9 onwards.
#

#https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/987/add-utility-functions-for-colors-to-help

RGBMAX = 0xff  # Corresponds to 255
HLSMAX = 240  # MS excel's tint function expects that HLS is base 240. see:
# https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9d8c136-6d62-4098-9b1b-dac786149f43/excel-color-tint-algorithm-incorrect?forum=os_binaryfile#d3c2ac95-52e0-476b-86f1-e2a697f24969

def rgb_to_ms_hls(red, green=None, blue=None):
    """Converts rgb values in range (0,1) or a hex string of the form '[#aa]rrggbb' to HLSMAX based HLS, (alpha values are ignored)"""
    if green is None:
        if isinstance(red, str):
            if len(red) > 6:
                red = red[-6:]  # Ignore preceding '#' and alpha values
            blue = int(red[4:], 16) / RGBMAX
            green = int(red[2:4], 16) / RGBMAX
            red = int(red[0:2], 16) / RGBMAX
        else:
            red, green, blue = red
    h, l, s = rgb_to_hls(red, green, blue)
    return (int(round(h * HLSMAX)), int(round(l * HLSMAX)), int(round(s * HLSMAX)))

def ms_hls_to_rgb(hue, lightness=None, saturation=None):
    """Converts HLSMAX based HLS values to rgb values in the range (0,1)"""
    if lightness is None:
        hue, lightness, saturation = hue
    return hls_to_rgb(hue / HLSMAX, lightness / HLSMAX, saturation / HLSMAX)

def rgb_to_hex(red, green=None, blue=None):
    """Converts (0,1) based RGB values to a hex string 'rrggbb'"""
    if green is None:
        red, green, blue = red
    return ('%02x%02x%02x' % (int(round(red * RGBMAX)), int(round(green * RGBMAX)), int(round(blue * RGBMAX)))).upper()


def get_theme_colors(wb):
    """Gets theme colors from the workbook"""
    # see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/I0k3TfqNLrc
    from openpyxl.xml.functions import QName, fromstring
    xlmns = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main'
    root = fromstring(wb.loaded_theme)
    themeEl = root.find(QName(xlmns, 'themeElements').text)
    colorSchemes = themeEl.findall(QName(xlmns, 'clrScheme').text)
    firstColorScheme = colorSchemes[0]

    colors = []

    for c in ['lt1', 'dk1', 'lt2', 'dk2', 'accent1', 'accent2', 'accent3', 'accent4', 'accent5', 'accent6']:
        accent = firstColorScheme.find(QName(xlmns, c).text)
        for i in list(accent): # walk all child nodes, rather than assuming [0]
            if 'window' in i.attrib['val']:
                colors.append(i.attrib['lastClr'])
            else:
                colors.append(i.attrib['val'])

    return colors

def tint_luminance(tint, lum):
    """Tints a HLSMAX based luminance"""
    # See: http://ciintelligence.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/converting-excel-theme-color-and-tint.html
    if tint < 0:
        return int(round(lum * (1.0 + tint)))
    else:
        return int(round(lum * (1.0 - tint) + (HLSMAX - HLSMAX * (1.0 - tint))))

def theme_and_tint_to_rgb(wb, theme, tint):
    """Given a workbook, a theme number and a tint return a hex based rgb"""
    rgb = get_theme_colors(wb)[theme]
    h, l, s = rgb_to_ms_hls(rgb)
    return rgb_to_hex(ms_hls_to_rgb(h, tint_luminance(tint, l), s))
```

Comment: Unbelievable how complicated that is for something i thought i'd have to do `cell.bgColor`

Comment: I fget an error :   rgb = get_theme_colors(wb)[theme]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Integer

Comment: This code doesn't work, because for some cells (in the example spreadsheet I am working on) `theme`, obtained via `theme = cell.fill.start_color.theme` is returned as some weird bootleg type `openpyxl.descriptors.base.Integer`. I Googled this and it is said to be a "synonym of builtins.int", but it behaves nothing like int. In particular, the code line `rgb = get_theme_colors(wb)[theme]` near the end errors because `theme` can't be used as an index. I can't even convert it to int with int_theme = int(theme). Go figure!

Comment: If you have a better version, please share it .. generally Excel seems to a pain to work with ..