# how to extract exact cell color with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have problem using `{cell}.fill.start_color.index` sometimes its return color code sometimes it don't

```
df = openpyxl.load_workbook(
    'csv_file/demo.xlsx')
ws = df['Sheet1']
print(ws['A1'].fill.start_color.index)
print(ws['A2'].fill.start_color.index)
print(ws['A3'].fill.start_color.index)
print(ws['A4'].fill.start_color.index)
print(ws['A5'].fill.start_color.index)
print(ws['A6'].fill.start_color.index)
```

```
output
----------
FFFFFF00
9
FF60497A
1
9
FF00B0F0
```

[image]

Do you have a way to extract the color from specific cell ? since I need to use their color to generate new column

**EDIT**

I have add this code

```
def convert_color_code(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x
    if isinstance(x, int):
        if x <= 64:
            return COLOR_INDEX[x]
        else:
            return x
```

[image]

```
output
-------
cell: start_color end_color
A1 :FFFFFF00 64
A2 :9 64
A3 :FF60497A 64
A4 :1 64
A5 :9 64
A6 :FF00B0F0 64
A7 :0 64
A8 :00000000 00000000
A1 :FFFFFF00 System Foreground
A2 :00FFFFFF System Foreground
A3 :FF60497A System Foreground
A4 :00FFFFFF System Foreground
A5 :00FFFFFF System Foreground
A6 :FF00B0F0 System Foreground
A7 :00000000 System Foreground
A8 :00000000 00000000
```

why black and dark green return the same value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get cell color from .xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736419/get-cell-color-from-xlsx)

Comment: @stovfl I have read that thread before, thing I don't understand is that why `a2` return `9`

Comment: ***"why `a2` return `9`"***: That's the `index` of the `COLOR_INDEX` table, which is `'00FFFFFF'`

Comment: I see, do you know how to make the return result more consistent? since some of it return index some of it return color code

Comment: ***"ome of it return index some of it return color code"***: I returns index if found in `COLOR_INDEX` table otherwise the hex value. You have to use a `if x <=64: return COLOR_INDEX[x] else: x`

Comment: thanks a lot,one last question,  I got `00000000` output for both start_color and end_color for both black and white color. Do you know how to separate this two color ?

Comment: ***"00000000 output for both start_color and end_color for both black and white color."***: Can't explaine, could it be `None` color is set?