# python openpyxl.load_workbook TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to read the backgrounf colors from an excel sheet. I'm trying this with openpyxl, but when i try to load the file
`openpyxl.load_workbook("myfile.xlsx", data_only=True)`
I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 55, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 279, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 192, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 102, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.fills = fills
  File "\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 26, in __set__
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>
```

What can I do to obtain this issue and read bg color like here: [Get cell color from .xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736419/get-cell-color-from-xlsx) ?

Comment: There's probably a bug in your XLSX file.

Answer (score 1):

So I was working through this nearly identical issue just today.  I found a pretty neat but kinda strange library that seems to ignore this fills issue.
I have these .xlsx files being generated and they don't open correctly with pandas/openpyxl for the same "Fill takes no arguments" error.

I found an **xlsreader** module in pip:
https://pypi.org/project/xlsxreader/

The following opens the .xlsx files in question perfectly, and sends them to a temp file in .csv form.

As far as I can tell it is the only thing it does.  I can't find much for documentation but I've gleaned that much, it **works** for me on these files, and was just updated last month.

```
import xlsreader
import csv

latest_xlsx_file = "D:\\testfile.xlsx"
# read it
thing = xlsxreader.readxlsx(latest_xlsx_file)
# get the name of the temporary .csv that was made
file = thing.name
# print the filename
print(file)
# open, or copy, or whatever the csv
with open(file, 'r') as CSV:
    read_csv = csv.reader(CSV, delimiter=",")
    read_csv = list(read_csv)
for r in read_csv:
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similiar issue and solved it later.you need try `pandas.read_excel(x, 'sheet1', index_col=None,  engine='openpyxl')`, specially, don't forget the "engine ='openpyxl' ".
panda bless you!!!

Comment: This did not help