# Edit .xlsx with python

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I Completely have no idea where to start.

I want to edit some think like:

[image]

To:
[image]

I want to save the result in a `.txt` file.

Every thing i know is to open and read the file.
**code:**

```
import pandas as pd
file = "myfile.xlsx"
f = pd.read_excel(file)
print(f)
```

I think the image colors speak for themselves how the code have to run. If not, I'll answer any question.

Comment: kkk... reason why I said "If not, I'll answer any question."

Answer (score 1):

My go-to for editing Excel spreadsheets is [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

I don't believe it can turn **.csv** or **.xlsx/xlsm** into **.txt** files, but it can read **.xlsx/xlsm** and save them as a **.csv**, and pandas can read csv files, so you can probably go from there

Quick example:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("foo.xlsx")
sheet = wb["baz"]
sheet["D5"] = "I'm cell D5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use openpyxl, and look at this below:

[Get cell color from .xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736419/get-cell-color-from-xlsx)

```
color_in_hex = sh['A2'].fill.start_color.index # this gives you Hexadecimal value of the color  (in cell A2)
```

So you'd have to iterate across your columns/rows checking for a colour match, then if its a match, grab the value and apply it to your new sheet